# ffill not retaining all columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a df like this:

```
Key    Class
1      Green
1      NaN
1      NaN
2      Red
2      NaN
2      NaN
```

and I want to forward fill `Class`.  Im using this code:

```
df=df.Class.fillna(method='ffill')
```

and this returns:

```
Green
Green
Green
Red
Red
Red
```

how can I retain the `Key` column while doing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
df['class'] = df.Class.fillna(method='ffill')
```

in your code you're assigning the whole dataframe to be the result , so instead you need to assign only the `class` column

or another way is to do the following

```
In [126]:
df.ffill()
Out[126]:
    Key Class
0   1   Green
1   1   Green
2   1   Green
3   2   Red
4   2   Red
5   2   Red
```

you can set also the `inplace` parameter to be `true` if you don't want to create a new copy from your `df`

```
df.ffill(inplace=True)
```